# Why the degree of freedom is NA ? And why the p value is calculated when the df is NA?

Tags: paired-data, degrees-of-freedom, lsmeans

I used R to do the statistical analysis. After running a glm model, I used Anova function to look at the p value for each explanatory variable. So far, everything was normal. However, when I used lsmeans to find out which combinations were different, I got the p values, but all the degree of freedoms were NA. I am really confused about this situation. In what situation, the df can be NA? Is the p value reliable if the df is NA? FYI, I have three explanatory variables, and there are 12, 2 and 5 levels for them, respectively. The problem still existed even when I used only one explanatory variable.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

NA is just a code that no degrees of freedom are needed. The tests and CIs are based on the standard normal rather than the *t* distribution. Note that the headings say *z* rather than *t*